# SearchBar in NavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

It's a bit difficult to explain my problem in one sentence so i'll put this two pictures here. 
I want this behaviour from my app. At first I got simple navigationBar with ButtonBarItems.
[image: navigation bar with 2 buttons]

And after search button is clicked i want this behaviour:
[image: search bar inside navigation bar]

How to achieve this behaviour?
I got up only with one idea - to create new view and place it , but it seems not like the best practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

u want t hide and show the search bar if search button clicked rite, do like below i used the tag t access the views for example i took one search bar and one bar button item and placed them in left and right side of the navigation bar like below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 { 
   [super viewDidLoad];

   UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 250,44)];
  searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
  UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:searchBar];
  searchBarItem.tag = 123;
  searchBarItem.customView.hidden = YES;
  searchBarItem.customView.alpha = 0.0f;
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = searchBarItem;

  UIBarButtonItem *leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Search" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(whenSearchClicked:)];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = leftItem;
}

- (void)whenSearchClicked:(id)sender
{
   NSArray *buttonsArray = self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItems;
  for(UIBarButtonItem *item in buttonsArray)
  {
      if(item.tag == 123 && item.customView.hidden)
      {
         item.customView.hidden = NO;
         if([item.customView isKindOfClass:[UISearchBar class]])
            [item.customView becomeFirstResponder];
         UIBarButtonItem *rightItem = self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem;//single rite item for this example
         [rightItem setTitle:@"Cancel"];
     }
     else
     {
         item.customView.hidden = YES;
         if([item.customView isKindOfClass:[UISearchBar class]])
             [item.customView resignFirstResponder];
         UIBarButtonItem *rightItem = self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem;//single rite item for this example, if u hav more than one just get the array "self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItems" and set by using tag like above
         [rightItem setTitle:@"Search"];

     }
  }

}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thx, almost what I wanted!) I reused code and actually got idea how to deal with such problems. Thx again.

Comment: Do you get the default UIKit animation as well?

Comment: @Rivera i don't get what u want, what u want " default UIKit animation "

Comment: Search bar animated to cover the whole navigation bar and dimming the underlying controller with a black translucent layer.

Comment: ohh, the animations like `UISearchDisplayController` shows the result by adding black translucent layer above the original view ... like that

Comment: i hav t try it in the above answer i did for just for search bar only not using `UISearchBar`